# Getting a PhD after two masters?

Tags: phd, masters, physics

So I am an undergraduate in university right now studying applied physics with applications in aeronautical/aerospace engineering. I have a 5th year M.S option to get my masters in physics with applications in a certain field. After that 5th year M.S I want to go and get my masters in aeronautical/aerospace engineering but always wanted to do research at the PhD level, so is it possible for me to get a PhD in physics or aerospace/aeronautical engineering after two MS's in physics and aeronautical engineering respectively?

Comment: Umm... I think it is clearly possible! Why would it be impossible?

Comment: I'm not saying it's impossible, I'm asking whether or not grad schools would look at an applicant with two masters or they would say no immediately. I understand that if you get a PhD it is very hard to go back and get another one unless it's some sort of honorary degree and/or you are an expert in your field and are world famous in the world of science.

Answer (score 2):

If you can afford to do all that graduate study without a TA-ship or RA-ship, more power to you!  Perhaps you could get the two masters concurrently... or at least get some of the coursework for the aeronautical/aerospace engineering masters out of the way.  Maybe there will be some nice overlap that will speed things up a bit for you.

You could also take those a/a courses in the early stages of a PhD program in either field.

Comment: I am blessed enough to not have any worries about finances. Is it possible to do two masters at the same time? If it is, wouldn't that be stupid of me in a 5th year MS in physics because I am going to be doing accelerated Masters anyway if I am in the 5th year program? I don't fathom the workload to graduate in two years with two masters.

Comment: Time to talk to an advisor from each department!  But first, read the programs of studies very carefully, and the relevant course descriptions.

Answer (score 0):

I did exactly this, just with some differences in the subjects.  I did my Masters degrees in Education and Physics and had no problem getting into the PhD in Physics. I am fortunate, as where I am, students are not required to pay for research degrees (Australia).

One major advantage I found was that the increased research skills benefited me in the PhD, this is what helped me when I was putting together my research proposal which my University's selection panel focused on.

If you can, go for it! As always though, speak with your advisor - it may be unnecessary.